# For Loop not working inside the Function in Python

Tags: python

```
lista=[4, 22, 5, 6, 32, 81, 729, 56, 77, 31]   
listb=[]

for k in range(len(lista)):
       listb.append(k) 
def cs():




   for i  in range(9):
              print(i)
              if lista[i]<lista[i+1]:
                print(i)
                listb[i]=lista[i]
                lista[i]=listb[i]
                i+=1
              else:

                listb[i]=lista[i+1]
                lista[i+1]=lista[i]
                lista[i]=listb[i]
              return(lista)   

print(cs())
```

Actually Iam sorting a list ,it is not working if Iam placing the same inside a function.But if i place the same code outside function it is working perfectly.Kindly help me

Comment: Could you translate this rambling into a coherent question, please?

Comment: And fix the indentation. Should the `return` statment really be _inside_ the loop?

Comment: `for k in lista: listb.append(k)` would be much cleaner. Iterate over values where possible, not indices.

Comment: Thanks landogardner.You are right.After removing the return statement outside the loop.It is working perfectly.my miss.Thanks

Comment: Thanks Chepner.I will do the same.

Comment: `for k in lista: listb.append(k)` will make `listb` equal to `lista`. Currently, `for k in range(len(lista)): listb.append(k)` results in `listb=[0, 1, 2, ..., 9]`. So it depends on what the intention is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` statement should be moved outside the `for` loop in your function, and also you should tidy up your whitespace, like so:

```
lista=[4, 22, 5, 6, 32, 81, 729, 56, 77, 31]   
listb=[]

for k in range(len(lista)):
    listb.append(k) 

def cs():
    for i in range(9):
        print(i)
        if lista[i]<lista[i+1]:
            print(i)
            listb[i]=lista[i]
            lista[i]=listb[i]
            i+=1
        else:
            listb[i]=lista[i+1]
            lista[i+1]=lista[i]
            lista[i]=listb[i]
    return(lista)   

print(cs())
```